# Java screen capture applet

Tags: java, sdk, applet, screen-capture

Am wondering if there is any applet which I can use and customize to capture the users screen (windows and mac) in java? I saw jxCapture but it takes only screen shots. I want to use the tool to capture the screen (for screencast) and then export as flv format.

Am wondering whats the best solution for that? Is there any applet/sdk that I can but and customize?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a similar thing a while back problem with java is you can't take screenshots fast enough i could not even get 1 fps

[Java Robot createScreenCapture performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646089/java-robot-createscreencapture-performance)

Comment: How did you find a solution? Is there a better way to do this? Thank you. How are screen-o-matic/screentoaster doing it?